# Creating swipe gesture in swift to scroll through image stack

Tags: ios, swift, gesture

I'm a swift newbie. Any help is appreciated.

I have a stack of 10 images. I want the user to be able to swipe up and down to update the the image view to new images.

For example: the Image View starts of by displaying 1.jpg. Then the user gestures down on the Image View and it updates the image to 2.jpg then 3.jpg... etc. depending on how far the gesture is held (kind of like an animation). I am able to update the image by one increment using the following code:

```
@IBAction func down(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

        image.image = UIImage(named: "2.jpg")

    }
```

How can I make this a continuous gesture?

The end result should look something like this: https://figure1.com/sections/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/resized.gif

Comment: Do you want to change image based on time, or on distance dragged?

Comment: Good question. Distance.

Comment: My advice would be to investigate UIPanGestureRecognizer (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/) which will call back its target when the gesture begins/ends and when position changes.  It responds to `translationInView:` which can be straight-forwardly modulo'd to an int in your image name space.

Answer (score 0):

So let's start off first things first.

**Based off the idea that this is distance dragged**

1) We need a `UIScrollView()`

2) Set the `Scrollview Frame` to the frame of the screen

3) Allow use of scrollview delegate, so add `UIScrollViewDelegate` to the list of subclasses (At the top where it says `ClassName: list, of, subclasses, here, separated, by, commas`)

4) In your class (If you are in your View Controller class), add the delegate to the scrollview

5) Let's set the `contentSize` of the scrollView

6) Let's add the `images` to your view, using a `loop`

7) Before step 6, make sure that your images are named something with numbers, and the same name, such as `Image1` `Image2` `Image3` so that we can loop through them.

8) Declare a `UIImage` array

9) I was gonna keep typing steps but here you go :P

```
class ViewController:UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    let images:[UIImage] = []
    let imageView:UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        //Setting up stuff
        for index in 0 ..< 10 {
            //It's either %t, %i or %d (I don't recall which is which lol)
            images.append(UIImage(named: String(format: "Image %i", index)))
        }            

        imageView = UIImageView(frame: view.bounds)
        imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        imageView.image = images[0]
        imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        self.view.addSubview(imageView)

        scrollView.frame = view.bounds
        scrollView.delegate = self
        scrollView.backGroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

        //Let's say every time the user drags to 1/10 of the screen, the picture will change
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height+(self.view.frame*(1/10)*CGFloat(images.count)))
        self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
    }

    //Now let's add some UIScrollView delegates to be called whenever the user scrolls!

    func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if(scrollView.contentOffSet.y > self.view.frame.height) {
            //(1/10) because we are changing the scrollView every 1/10 of the screen
            let pictureCount = scrollView.contentOffset.y/scrollView.frame.height*(1/10)
            imageView.image = images[pictureCount]
        }
    }
}
```

Don't quote me off this, mainly because I pulled it out of the air, so if it has errors/bugs, I apologize, but feel free to comment and I will try to adjust what is needed.

Comment: Why didn't you opt for a UIPanGestureRecognizer (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/).  In the action method, one can call `translationInView:` to get the dragged distance.  Seems like this (possibly otherwise fine) suggestion could be replaced by about 3 lines.

Comment: Well, a Pan Gesture allows me to drag, and move things, "UIPanGestureRecognizer is a concrete subclass of UIGestureRecognizer that looks for panning (dragging) gestures." But what you are wanting to achieve is after a certain dragging length, change something, which is exactly what UIScrollViews are used for, as well as various other things. I am new myself(kinda) but I would personally use a `UIScrollView()` or make a new class `ScrollView:UIScrollView` and then call `ScrollView().` Now, if you think panning is better, by all means!

Comment: I see a lot of `Pan Gestures` that allow me to drag and drop something or that allow dragging this object here, etc. Such as a 2 finger drag movement (similar to scrolling on a Mac). Now, this is just from my judgement based, but that is my solution to your problem.

Comment: I mean, I guess you could add an `ImageView` for changing images, then on top of that a `UIView` or `UIButton` that would have the Pan Gesture, then as you moved, determine the location of the gesture and do some math to determine distance, to change images. Never really thought of it. I enjoy scrollViews, personally.

Comment: :-) yep... you can attach the pan gesture recognizer directly to the image view (no need for another view, but you must set userInteractionEnabled = YES on the image view).  Then, conveniently, the GR does the math for you, providing a method called `translationInView:`.  With that, rounded and modulo the number of images, you get your image number.  We don't really want to move anything as a result of the gesture (i.e. dragging, the way a scroll view does).  We just want to measure finger motion and translate it to an image name.

Comment: I feel ya! I may have gone about it in a strange way, my usual nutcase lol! Good luck!